Get Sender ID from notification in background on Android
I want to get sender_id from notification when user click to notificaion in background on Android. How can I do this on Android?
In foreground state, sender id can archive through onMessageReceived on FirebaseMessagingService class, but I don't know how to in background state
Foreground:
override fun onMessageReceived(message: RemoteMessage) {
    val senderId = message.from
    ...
}

Background:
???

Actually, there is no direct way of accessing the sender_id as Firebase automatically creates a notification when your app is in background. So, to get the sender_id, what you'll need to do is add data in notification payload.
For example-
{
    "to": "<device_token>",
    "data": {
        "sender_id": "12345",
        "other_data": "value"
    },
    "notification": {
        "title": "Title",
        "body": "Message body"
    }
}

Now, in the LauncherActivity or MainActivity, which ever is the first activity of your app, check if it is opened from notification or not, and then get the sender_id.
MainActivity.java or LauncherActivity.java or whatever-
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    
    // Check if the intent contains the data payload
    if (getIntent().getExtras() != null) {
        String senderId = getIntent().getExtras().getString("sender_id");
        // Use the senderId as needed
    }
}

